# Rails Create article with other user not current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I would like to create an **article** with other user **not current_user** and for that **I'm saving in a session the id to the other user** and I recover this id with a collection in the view to this point everything work fine but when I'm trying to use my **helper :selected_user** into my articles controller with a **if sentence** doesn't work here is my code:

```
def new
    if selected_user.present?
      @article = selected_user.articles.build state: :step1
      render_wizard
    else
      @article = current_user.articles.build state: :step1
      render_wizard
    end
  end
```

so, I'm asking **if the selected_user.present?** I would like to create the article with this user_id **but else I would like to create it with the current_user**

my create method is:

```
def create
  if selected_user.present?
    step = :step1

    @article = selected_user.articles.build article_params_step1
    @article.state = step.to_s

    if @article.save
      redirect_to wizard_path(next_step, article_id: @article)
    else
      render_wizard
    end
  else
    step = :step1

    @article = current_user.articles.build article_params_step1
    @article.state = step.to_s

    if @article.save
      redirect_to wizard_path(next_step, article_id: @article)
    else
      render_wizard
    end
  end
end
```

so, yeah when I run my view the controller jump to the else section.

**just for clarify my selected_user not return nil but here is the implementation:**

**selections_controller.rb:**

```
class SelectionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def create
    session[:selected_user_id] = params[:user][ :user_id]
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

**and in my application_controller.rb:**

```
helper_method :selected_user

def selected_user
  @selected_user ||= User.find(session[:selected_user_id])
end
```

and in the view:

```
<%= form_tag( { :controller => "selections", :action => "create" } , :class => "navbar-form navbar-left") do %>
 <%= collection_select(:user, :user_id, User.all, :id, :name, prompt: "Escoge cliente")%>
 <%= submit_tag 'Enviar'  %>
<% end %>
```

if I try create an article without select an user from my collection appear this error:

```
Couldn't find User with 'id'=
```

but when I select my user from the collection everything works fine. so just I want when I don't select nothing create with the current_user.

Thanks for your time !

Regards !

Comment: Could you please include the code for the `selected_user` helper method?

Comment: what's the error you're getting?

Comment: If you are expecting `selected_user` to return the user saved in the session (not the current_user), but is returning `nil`, then there seems to be something wrong in the `selected_user` logic. Please provide the implementation details of `selected_user` for further review.

Comment: okay thanks ! I edited my post @Dharam

Comment: Did you check the value of `session[:selected_user_id]` within the `selected_user` ? Also check what `User.find(session[:selected_user_id])` is returning.

Comment: Also `session[:selected_user_id] = params[:user][ :id]` may not work. Based on your view, `collect_select` is going to send the `params[:user][:user_id]` not params[:user][:id]. May be thats where the bug is.

Comment: I edited my collect select @Dharam and after that I check it my **session[:selected_user_id]** with a **binding.pry** and return the correct id but I have the same error into the controller for create I'm trying to make diferents questions like **selected_user.empty? selected_user.id?** I don't know nothing works

Comment: Are you saying that both `session[:selected_user_id` and `User.find(session[:selected_user_id])` are returning the expected values, but the `selected_user` is returning `nil`?

Comment: @Dharam yes the both return the expected values and for that I feel so confuse because it should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you were seeing the error

`Couldn't find User with 'id'=`

when you haven't selected a `user` was that the `session[:selected_user_id]` was `nil` and your old `selected_user` with following code was throwing the error.

```
def selected_user
  @selected_user ||= User.find(session[:selected_user_id])
end
```

`User.find` method expects either a single `id` or an array of `ids`. If you give a single `id` and if it finds the relevant record in the database then it will returns that instance. If you give an array of ids and if it finds those relevant records in the database, then it will return array of those instances. But if you pass `nil` to it, then it will through the error `Couldn't find User with 'id'=` as it won't find a relevant record.

But your updated `selected_user` implementation:

```
def selected_user
  @selected_user ||= session[:selected_user_id] && User.find_by_id(session[:selected_user_id])
end
```

is working because, first you are checking for the existence of `session[:selected_user_id]` value and second you are using `User.find_by_id` instead of `User.find`.

`User.find_by_id` either returns a single instance of the record if it finds it in the database or will return `nil` if it doesn't find the record. It will never through an error.

Refer to [ActiveRecord#find](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find) and [ActiveRecord#find_by](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find_by) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why is working and what is the different but my solution for the problem it was to add this to my **selected_user** method:

```
def selected_user
  @selected_user ||= session[:selected_user_id] && User.find_by_id(session[:selected_user_id])
end
```

and with that I don't have the nil error and entry to the if statement without errors.